# YouTube no WebView para app Android

Tags: java, android, streaming, webview

Alguém sabe como visualizar um vídeo do YouTube ou algum *streaming* de vídeo através de uma `WebView`?

No código abaixo, existem três botões. O primeiro leva o usuário ao link que ele digitou, o segundo está fixo para direcionar ao site do Google e o terceiro deveria rodar o *streaming* de vídeo da NasaTV, porém fica apenas carregando. Também tentei colocar um link do YouTube e não executa através do `WebView`.

Meu código:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText editText;
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewlayout);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
}

public void abrirPagina (View v){
    String url = editText.getText().toString();
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

public void acessoDireto (View v){
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.br");
}

public void nasaTV (View v){
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.ustream.tv/nasahdtv");
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient{
    public boolean overrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

Meu manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.luizhmu.aulas_android_webview" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: Até aonde entendo, os navegadores mobile não abrem diretamente o vídeo, eles chamam o aplicativo reprodutor de vídeo instalado (e padrão) do seu smartphone, sendo assim, se o vídeo só fica "carregando" e nunca chama o aplicativo de player do celular é por que a página exibida está usando um player em *Flash* (a maioria dos smartphones não trabalham com *Flash*) ou há algo de errado com o seu reprodutor de vídeo do seu smartphone. (Note: que a página http://m.ustream.tv/nasahdtv acessando por simuladores Desktop também não carrega nada, mas se clicar em "vídeos" e selecionar um vídeo qualquer).

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite Luiz!

Ao invés de utilizar o webview para ver os vídeos, use um VideoView.
Utilize a webview apenas para visualizar páginas.

Então acrescente um VideoView e siga o código exemplo abaixo:

```
    VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
    String vidAddress = "http://r3---sn-oxupm-nv4e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?signature=BC3A63220C594522C360CB7486FC1E8D12DCDAB8.CAC1407F3FE7F20EFCAA52A0CAE0CF326F9ED28F&expire=1420274975&mv=m&initcwndbps=1832500&mt=1420253339&ms=au&ipbits=0&itag=18&mm=31&id=o-ANfN_ioVopr0rRldVzihGYKSVBcW128i3qCtQdgFUZD1&ip=82.118.249.190&key=yt5&source=youtube&sver=3&dur=546.597&fexp=900718%2C916644%2C927622%2C932404%2C933112%2C9406025%2C941004%2C942632%2C943917%2C947209%2C947218%2C948124%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C955105%2C955301%2C957103%2C957105%2C957201&ratebypass=yes&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=hpPTxmA5wT8&title=DevBytes-+Criando+seu+primeiro+projeto+no+Android+Studio";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
    video.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    video.start();
```

OBS: esse link gigantesco é de um video do youtube com o link já convertido para visualização direta.

Teste aí e me avise. Aqui funcionou perfeitamente. Abraço.

Comment: Desculpe MagnusMaker, mas preciso comentar, esse link geralmente muda, não é recomendável, as estruturas de "stream", o problema dele é outra coisa.

Comment: Obrigado pelo aviso, eu realmente não sabia disso. Mas é um método que funciona para links permanentes também (caso tenha um link fixo .mp4 por exemplo). De qualquer forma, se entendi errado favor desconsiderar então.

Comment: Sim para links fixos funciona perfeitamente e assim não será necessário sair do aplicativo, assim como funciona o aplicativo oficial do YouTube. A principio podemos dizer que até a sua solução funcione, mas se ele vier a querer desenvolver um WebBrowser, então ainda sim o problema irá existir, já que ocorre com dois sites de vídeo diferente, então o problema ainda existiria. Espero que leve isto como um comentário construtivo.

Comment: Tranquilo.. estou aqui para aprender acima de tudo e qualquer correção é bem vinda.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela intenção em ajudar!! De fato eu preciso que o streaming rode através do VideoView mas estou ciente que não seja uma boa prática. Diferente do iOS, o Android tem essas particularidades. Mas ainda assim, se souberem de algo que possa acrescentar, serei muito grato. Abraços.  @Guilherme Nascimento

Comment: Nao é isso @LuizHenriqueUgliano acredito que o seu app até funcione, o problema deve ser algo que citei no meu primeiro comentário, a página deve estar tentando carregar o player em Flash ao invés de html5 (tag `<video>`).